¿Como puedo hacer un date picker pequeño?
estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación, pero al momento de poner un date picker o un time picker solo me pone el cuadro directamente con el reloj/calendario, y quiero algo más pequeño que me pueda desplegar el reloj en vez de tenerlo en pantalla ¿Alguien sabrá como hacerlo?

Básicamente esto es lo que me da.

que es esto: asp, winforms, wpf, maui, xamarin, winui, blazor, unity...etc?

El programa esta en Xamarin, C# y XML
